# How to use find_all method in bs4 on an object without class

Tags: python, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result=requests.get('http://textfiles.com/stories/').text
soup=BeautifulSoup (result, 'lxml')
stories=soup.find_all('tr')
print (stories)
```

The `find` method works but `find_all` doesn't I'm not sure why maybe it is because it doesn't have a class?

Comment: Your code are full of errors. Get them fixed before others can help. For examples, result vs results, request vs requests, ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

correct code is

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result=requests.get('http://textfiles.com/stories/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html5lib')
stories=soup.find_all('tr')
```

you can access each 'tr' by

```
stories[0]
```

0 can be replaced with any number in list
You can also use Pandas
eg

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result=requests.get('http://textfiles.com/stories/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'html5lib')
df=pandas.read_html(soup.prettify())
print(df)
```